# How can I use values read from TFRecords as arguments to tf.set_shape?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to do something like this:

```py
height = tf.cast(features['height'],tf.int32)
width = tf.cast(features['width'],tf.int32)
image.set_shape(tf.pack([height,width,3]))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) to [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.set_shape). The only way to use a value read from a TFRecord as the argument to `set_shape()` is to evaluate it (e.g. using `sess.run()`) and pass the resulting NumPy array to `set_shape()`.

The reason for this limitation is somewhat subtle. `Tensor.set_shape()` is used to make assertions about the shapes of *all* values that a particular `Tensor` (i.e. a symbolic value) can hold. In particular, it is used to fill the gaps left by shape inference, when the programmer knows more about that data than the library can infer. However, these assertions can only use information that is available at graph construction time. Dynamically-varying shapes are represented using the special values `Dimension(None)` (for an unknown dimension) and `TensorShape(None)` (for a tensor of unknown rank).

The intent throughout TensorFlow is that most operations should be able to work without statically known shapes, so that tensors of dynamically varying shape can be used. However, there are a few exceptions among the [image processing ops used for cropping/padding](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#cropping):

- [`tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#crop_to_bounding_box)
- [`tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#pad_to_bounding_box)
- [`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#resize_image_with_crop_or_pad)

These three ops require that the shape is statically known. However, they are simply convenience wrappers around [`tf.pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pad) and [`tf.slice()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice) that take advantage of the static shape to avoid doing needless computation in every step. We've been slowly removing this dependency from the image ops, but feel free to raise a GitHub issue about this. In the meantime, you can use the lower-level ops directly to work around the lack of shape inference for your dynamic tensors.

Comment: How can we restore the shape of the tensor when we construct the graph? As we know, in a TFRecords file, the image data is flattened, and the network must be fed with image of size `H` x `W`. Now `H` and `W` are stored in the TFRecords, but we cannot use set_shape(). So how? (I believe we should not launch a session to evaluate it)