# Why doesn't `tf.image.resize_images` set the image shape?

Tags: tensorflow

My objective is to introduce random scaling and translation for data augmentation purposes.

```
distorted_image = tf.image.resize_images(distorted_image, random_scale, random_scale)
distorted_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(distorted_image, random_y, random_x, 299, 299)
```

This fails with `'image' must be fully defined.` Swapping the lines works, but doesn't do what I really need.

```
distorted_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(distorted_image, random_y, random_x, 299, 299)  
distorted_image = tf.image.resize_images(distorted_image, random_scale, random_scale)
```

So it seems like resize_images loses the shape of the image tensor and then `crop_to_bouding_box` fails. Is this on purpose, am I missing something? How come `random_crop` works after a resize but `crop_to_bounding_box` doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tf.image.resize_images()` op *does* set the image shape, on [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/34880c4ca1a83b443b44dc415b74deb217c42257/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.py#L675) of the implementation. (This was added in TensorFlow 0.7.)

However, if either of the `new_height` or `new_width` arguments is a dynamic value, then TensorFlow cannot infer a single shape for that dimension, and so uses `None` for that dimension. I notice in your code that the new height and width values are called `random_scale`: if a new random value is drawn on each step, then the shape will have `None` for the height and width dimensions.

Note that in this case, the `tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box()` op will not work because—as the error message indicates—the current implementation requires that the shape of the input be fully defined. As I noted in [a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35777637/3574081), the best workaround might be to use the lower level ops from which [`tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/image.html#crop_to_bounding_box) is implemented (in particular [`tf.slice()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice) with computed indices).

Comment: I ended up inlining `random_crop` and doing small modifications and that worked like  a charm. Thanks!